# Access to the Path is Denied (Downloading files from ftp to local drive)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, iis, iis-7

I am downloading the files from ftp to my local folder. 
In middle of program I am getting an frequent error : Access to the path is denied in my local folder: c:\users\Project.

Note: I am running under adminstrator

I hardly tried to search at everywhere,but I cant find the solution.

```
     Getting the Error at: FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);

Here is the code:-

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* Create Object Instance */
        ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://xxxxxxx/", "user123", "pass123");



        /* Download a File */
        ftpClient.download("werty.docx", @"C:\users\Project");

    }
}


 public ftp(string hostIP, string userName, string password)
  { host = hostIP; user =   userName; pass = password; }

    /* Download File */
    public void download(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
        try
        {
            /* Create an FTP Request */
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
            /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            /* When in doubt, use these options */
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            /* Open a File Stream to Write the Downloaded File */
            FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);

           // FileSystemInfo 
            /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            /* Download the File by Writing the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
            try
            {
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Resource Cleanup */
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled on your machine? Might need to run under admin if you are.

Comment: I am running under admin only

Comment: Funny one has occurred to me more than once make sure no process is using the file you are trying to save to the local drive this will abort the process and gives a permission error.

Comment: Isolate the problem, does it work without the FTP?

Comment: Can you try `((IDisposeable)localFileStream).Dispose();`